# jQuery Object Does not Support Validate method

Tags: jquery

I am getting error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'" on the following line in the script:

```
 $('#MainForm').validate({
```

The "MainForm" is the ID of the form element.  I thought that HTML form supports validate() method.  What am I missing?

Comment: Validate is a plugin, not automatically included - http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation

Comment: @null Thank you.  I have included "jquery-ui.datepicker.validation.min.js" as outlined on this site: http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html. I thought that was all I needed.

Comment: I see that I missed to include "jquery.validate.js" Sorry for my mistake.